# Who was Sue cosplaying as in Genshiken Nidaime episode 4?

Tags: genshiken

Who was Sue cosplaying as in *Genshiken Nidaime* episode 4?

This was when she cosplayed when they were trying to get the doujin finished and she wanted Ogiue to cosplay as Azusa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this episode Sue is cosplaying as [Comic Master J](http://myanimelist.net/manga/12562/Comic_Master_J), the titular character in the manga of the same name. Here's a comparison (based on manga, but clearly the same character):

[image]

Comic Master J is essentially unheard-of in the west, but it had 13 volumes and was reasonably popular and well-received in Japan. There's no Wikipedia page in English, but the [Japanese article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BCJ) has some nice details. Here's a brief summary (written by me, adapted from several sources):

> Comic Master J is a mysterious super assistant-mangaka who can instantly finish the production of any manga for 5 million yen, so long as it is made with "soul". The story follows Comic Master J and the various mangaka he helps, gradually revealing more about him and the various mysteries that surround him

Comment: Cool, thanks, I thought it was a van helsing integra thing. The references are starting to get obscure....

Comment: Thank you for the information! The moment She came out of the room I fell in love with that outfit! I wish I could recognize all the other references though xD like Fuyume's book of friends! That was hilarious 